# Passing the "-j" argument to ninja from gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake, ninja

I need to pass `-j` argument to ninja while building Android app with gradle.
(on Windows)

Why do I need this?
- We have huge unified c++ files that require lots of memory to compile. Currently I have no enough memory (~10GB free) to compile them in parallel on 8 cores. Thus clang fails when memory runs out.

I see that gradle runs `cmake` with `--build` key so I've tried to add my `-j1` arg there. But seems `arguments` field is used only for cmake generation, because it doesn't affect command line passed to cmake in build stage.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cFlags "..."
        cppFlags "..."
        arguments "... -- -j1"
    }
}
```

The only way I see now it to replace `ninja` with some wrapper to pass `-j` from there. But this is the last options I would like to use.
Appreciate any ideas about how to achieve this valid way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set `CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL` environment variable to number of concurrent processes you want to use for the build.

It's available since cmake 3.12.4.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/envvar/CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL.html